# Google Chrome Extension got rejected multiple times for "User Data Privacy"

Tags: chrome-web-store

I submitted a Google Chrome Extension and got rejected

> Your item did not comply with the following section of our Program Policies:
>
> "User Data Privacy"
>
> The Privacy Policy & Secure Transmission section requires that:
>
> If your product handles personal or sensitive user data (including
>   personally identifiable information, financial and payment
>   information, health information, authentication information, website
>   content and resources, form data, web browsing activity, user-provided
>   content and personal communications), then your product must:
>
> Post a privacy policy. Handle the user data securely, including
>   transmitting it via modern cryptography. To comply with this policy:
>
> Provide a working link to your privacy policy in the appropriate field
>   in the Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard. The link must lead to a
>   privacy policy that is owned by you. The privacy policy must also
>   accurately and fully disclose all the details pertaining to how your
>   product collects, uses and shares user data, including the types of
>   parties with whom the data is shared. For more information on the
>   policy, please refer to the User Data FAQ.
>
> Once your item complies with Chrome Web Store policies, you may
>   request re-publication in the Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard.
>   Your item will be reviewed for policy compliance prior to
>   re-publication.
>
> If you have any questions about this email, please respond and the
>   Chrome Web Store Developer Support team will follow up with you.

Our privacy policy is [here](https://keepkash.com/en/privacy-policy)

How could I fix it? What should I do?

Comment: Questions like this aren't directly related to development and thus are off-topic for StackOverflow. The web store review process is known to not make any sense in general so try asking for support on Google product forums e.g. [this one](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-extensions).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks, I already did, but I find stack overflow more responsive, if it's OK I would like to keep it, maybe somebody else had the same experience

Comment: Lots of people have the same experience but it's caused by the nontransparent and often nonsensical review process of the web store so this is outside of the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: @wOxxOm I see, so do I have to remove it, or can I keep it?

Comment: It'll get closed eventually so it's up to you. Personally I don't believe this can be solved in a logical fashion as I have zero trust for the web store review process, it's 99% bot-driven.

Comment: What did you learn eventually?

Comment: @JonathanLin - I replied to them for more details and eventually after couple of emails they said the exact reasons, they were 2, the snapshot did not reflect the actual extension (it was a prettified design) and I had a missing permission justification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few emails with google asking about the exact issue, it turns out the User Data policy is a big section and a lot of thing might go wrong there, however, in my case I had a snapshot that is actually created by a designer to look pretty, not a snapshot from the actual extension and I had a permission that did not have a justification description. After I replaced the snapshot with an actual one and I removed the permission that didn't have a description because I actually didn't use it. The extension was approved and published.

Comment: When you say snapshot, do you mean a screenshot?  They all have to be from the actual extension?

Comment: @derekdata Yes, exactly